# Hibernate multiple join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am little confuse while fetching products in HQL.
Product has multiple SKUs and SKU has multiple availibility..
Below is my hql query.

```
select distinct p from Product p 
join p.skus sku
join sku.availibility a
where sku.skuType = "DEFAULT" AND a.available = true && a.day = 5;
```

I have to filter the products where skuType is "DEFAULT" and  availiblity of only that sku("DEFAULT" type). 
I am confused because.. I am thinking in above query available and a.day part will check in all the skus not just the default sku.. 
How this query behave ?
Am i wrong ? IF yes then how can be query structured for this ?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Your query will only return a set of `products P`, where each `e` in `P` matches the following:

1. `e` has a `SKU` which has `skuType="DEFAULT"` AND
2. `e` has a `SKU` which is `skuType="DEFAULT"` AND that `SKU` has `availability a` WHERE `a.available = true && a.day = 5`

Your comment

> I am thinking in above query available and a.day part will check in all the skus not just the default sku..

Yes, It the query execution will loop through your `CROSS JOIN` set, but it will **ONLY RETURN** products that match the conditions given above.